# How can I repeat the headers of an iTextSharp PdfPTable on each page?

Tags: row, itext, repeat, pdfptable, tableheader

How can I get iTextSharp to repeat the headers of a PdfPTable on each page of the generated PDF?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You just need to set the `PdfPTable.HeaderRows` property to the number of rows in your `PdfPTable`'s header like this:

```
table.HeaderRows = 1;
```

Comment: sample: `table.HeaderRows = 1;` This repeats the 1st row for all pages as a header for that PdfTable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HeaderRows as follows:

```
            var dataDetails = new PdfPTable(6);
            dataDetails.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            dataDetails.WidthPercentage = 100;
            dataDetails.SpacingBefore = 10;
            dataDetails.SpacingAfter = 10;
            dataDetails.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
            dataDetails.HeaderRows = 1;
            dataDetails.SetWidths(new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
```