# Base Template for PDF generation in iText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I will have to grab the data from database and construct a PDF file (in the same table format) and should give back to front-end users.

I feel very difficult to code in iText-java for table-header creation and for subheaders, the allignment is not good and professional.

Please tell, is there any predefined-template with which i can design how-my-table-should-appear and generate pdfs with values.

Thanks in Advance friends :-)

Comment: please have a look at [Flying saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText is a little complicated to start with, but you can *always* get it to layout pretty much exactly as you want.

I think what you might need is this:

[How can I repeat the headers of an iTextSharp PdfPTable on each page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062983/itextsharp-how-repeat-headers-of-pdfptable-on-each-page)

Comment: Thanks for your solution paddy. I will try and let you know if any more help I would like to get

Comment: Paddy, it seems iTextSharp is not for java and its for cSharp only. Am programming in java. However, my need is to get a PDF table template and will have to fill the values inside the table (professionally-designed-table). Can you help me by suggesting some good tool for this (ofcourse an open-source-tool) ?? Thanks Once again :)

Comment: iTextSharp is a port of iText for C#.  It uses much the same function calls etc, but sometimes slight syntax changes.  If iTextSharp has this functionality, the iText must do as well.

Comment: Hi Paddy, How are you ? Still I didnt get any solution for this. Any other tool can u suggest where i can create professional tables and insert values ? something like jxl for excel-generation